# Best Drive/OS Encryption Tool [Windows]

Tags: security, encryption

So, I' about to re-install on to Windows 8.1 and ever since the TrueCrypt saga I've been on the lookout for a tool to replace it.

It needs to be free, and it needs to support full OS encryption, whilst of course maintaining the level of security that you expect from such a tool.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just BitLocker?

Comment: I don't have a TPM chip.

Answer (score 1):

I see only two real good alternatives to TrueCrypt: their descendant VeraCrypt and, as another variant, GnuPG. VeraCrypt is a fork of TrueCrypt, that is still in development and it just passed an independent audit of its code. VeraCrypt can create a virtual encrypted disk within a file or encrypt a partition or storage device. GnuPG is an alternative, which is used by many experienced users for their "black" needs, such as communication with sellers in black markets.